# Security in laravel project - API interconnection

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, security, server

I have a new project that contains two separate parts for backend and frontend, and based on it, I want to establish a secure connection through the frontend subproject (designed with vuejs 3) with the server side API code (designed with Laravel 10).
Can anyone give me a suggestion that I can establish a secure connection between the frontend sub-project and the API sub-project in such a way that it has the following conditions.

**1- No one can extract data by copying codes and illegal access to API**
**2- The API server should be hidden from users as much as possible.**

Explanation:
I am thinking of a proxy server or secure proxy channel.

More Explain:
I have an api that services to different client app. like `telegram` messenger app! so i want to service to the specify web apps and block the illegal apps to use my api.

Comment: You can't. Use server side rendering if you don't want this to happen. Everything that happens on client side can be tampered.

Comment: thanks @EstusFlask, its ok. i know server side rendering. but i want to find new struct for this problem. like proxy server.

Comment: It's unclear how you expect this to work. Do you mean reverse proxy? A user will see the requests to proxy server instead. Any requests that are done on client side are seen in browser console and can be analyzed, this is not the only way how the website can be debugged by a culprit but a simple one.

Comment: Simply copying code should not give anyone access to anything. Surely they would also have to authenticate?

Comment: Note that the users are not mentioned here and before the users, it is important that the requesting system is valid. so maybe we need another kind authenticate from normal.

Comment: @EstusFlask could you explain your idea?

Comment: I'd suggest to check the capabilities of browser dev tools. Anything that a browser does a culprit can easily recognize and reproduce. That's why native app is one step away from web app in terms of api safety. Can you elaborate on your case further?

Comment: You can use laravel sanctum to implement personal access tokens (PAT) to authenticate the API requests, alongside with CSRF

Comment: Minify your JS so it's hard to understand when copied. Use HTTPs for the connection. Employ CSRF, PAT tokens, API tokens, captcha, CORS restrictions, things like that - the exact choices depending on your exact situation of course

Comment: tanks @EstusFlask, thats it, i want to avoid this problem. i have api that servises to different client app. like `telegram` messenger app! so i want to service to the specify web apps and block the illegal apps to use my api.

Comment: tanks @ElioBteich, its help me. if u want to answer an explain `laravel sanctum`, i'll accept your answer.

Comment: You can't block illegal apps from using your api. You can proxy third-party apis through your api indeed, this way you can set proper cors, rate limit or ban users. Neither of this fully prevents from misusing your api and certainly doesn't prevent from discovering it. It's still unclear if you authenticate users or allow anyone to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel sanctum to implement personal access tokens (PAT) to authenticate the API requests, thus preventing unauthenticated users from accessing your API endpoint, alongside with CSRF tokens that can prevent sending requests from a different origin.

By sending a GET request to /your-domain/sanctum/csrf-cookie, an XSRF-TOKEN cookie sent from sanctum will be attached automatically to your browser, that you have to include in the "X-XSRF-TOKEN" header of every subsequent request sent from your frontend.

On top of that, when you login you need to create an auth token for the user if the credentials are correct, this token should be sent back in the response, and stored in the client browser (in the local storage for instance), and should be included in the Authorization header of future requests, here's how it could be implemented:

In you laravel AuthController:

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {

        // Validate user input
        $request->validate([
            'login' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

            

        // Attempt user authentication
        $user = $this->authService->authenticateUser($request->login, $request->password);

            

        // Check if existing tokens exist and delete them (optional)
        if ($user->tokens()) {
            $user->tokens()->delete();
        }

            
        // Create a new token for the user
        $token = $user->createToken('auth-token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'authToken' => $token,
            'message' => 'Connected successfully!'
        ]);
        
    }
```

On the client side (using axios):

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/api`,
    withCredentials: true, // This ensures that cookies are sent with cross-origin requests.
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {

    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if (authToken) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;
    }

    const csrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

    if (csrfToken) {
        config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;
    }

    return config;
});

const getCookie = (name) => {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) {
        return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
    return null;
}


export default api;
```

I use a request interceptor to include the csrf and auth token in the header of every request intercepted.

After that you will be able to use the laravel sanctum middleware in your routes to block unauthenticated requests like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/getAuth', [AuthController::class, 'getAuth']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

NB: Don't forget to configure the config/cors.php to allow requests from your frontend:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => false,

    'max_age' => false,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

So, in summary, the attacker may be able to send a /sanctum/csrf-cookie API request from a different domain and have it processed, but they would likely be blocked by the browser from reading the response containing the CSRF token due to the Same-Origin Policy.

Here's the documentation of sanctum for full details: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum

Hope it will help!

Comment: thanks @elio-bteich , it`s very good answer. this is good Authentication with sanctum but i need more than this. i need some process to Validation client apps not Authenticat users. but so thanks for your time!